# Programmatically reconnect to wifi network

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, wireless-networking, script

Sometimes I work with frequently-dropping wifi connections.

I can either reconnect manually or wait some time (varies from few seconds to few minutes) before windows attempts to reconnect. Is there a simple way to trigger reconnect immediately after the connection was dropped?

Bonus question: In this particular case I'd blame hardware, but how can I diagnose the reason of dropping connection in general?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the Windows Wireless Zero Configuration Service. You only need this if you are going to be connecting to multiple access points. It is probably dropping because it detects another access point in range and trys to connect, but fails. You can also check your Preferred Networks and put your access point to the highest point.

Comment: WCZ is also known as WLAN AutoConfig in later versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> In this particular case I'd blame
>   hardware, but how can I diagnose the
>   reason of dropping connection in
>   general?

"frequently-dropping wifi connections" are often caused by the power saving facility of the WLAN adapter, change the settings to OFF or CAM (constantly awake mode).